# Trying to update database -- Get error wrong number of arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm adding attendance tracking to my app, with basic clock-in/clock-out ability

I get `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` for this line:

```
scope :running, -> { where(clock_out: nil).where.not(clock_in: nil) }
```

This is what I have:

**Controller:**

```
class AttendenceRecordsController < ApplicationController
  def clock_in
    @clock_in = current_user.attendence_records.create(clock_in: DateTime.current)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @clock_in.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: "You've clocked in successfully" }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: "Something went wrong, you were not clocked in" }
      end
    end

  end

  def clock_out
    current_user.attendence_records.running.first.finish!
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: "You've clocked out successfully" }
    end

  end
end
```

**Model**

```
class AttendenceRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users


  scope :running, -> { where(clock_out: nil).where.not(clock_in: nil) }

  def finish!
    update(clock_out: DateTime.current)
  end
end
```

**Routes**

```
Mysupport::Application.routes.draw do

  put "attendence_records/clock_in", to: "attendence_records#clock_in", as: :attendence_clock_in
  put "attendence_records/clock_out", to: "attendence_records#clock_out", as: :attendence_clock_out

end
```

**View**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><%= link_to "Clock In", attendence_clock_in_path, method: :put %></li>
                  <li><%= link_to "Clock Out", attendence_clock_out_path, method: :put %</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where.not` is introduced in Rails 4

For Rails 3, use

```
where('clock_in is not null')
```

Comment: It worked. However, it doesn't update the database record? Am I doing something wrong on the controller?

Comment: @meritonch you should probably use `update_attributes({clock_out: DateTime.current})`, if you want to see errors, put `!` in the end, like `update!(clock_out: DateTime.current)`. `update` is an alias for `update_attributes` in Rails 4

Comment: yeah i figured it out, thanks! .... Everything works great now. ... Any direction you want to steer me for creating reports and report views?

Comment: @meritonch sorry, but I don't know your requirements, it is better to try yourself and if you'll face difficulties - post new question with detailed description of the problem appeared

Comment: Thanks! -- I'll give it a try. Thanks for everything

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Rails do you use?

In Rails 3.x `where.not` is not implemented.